# Tab Listener not Getting Activated by Message from Background Script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am sending a message to the tab were I have a content script (getTradingData.js) from the background.js with the following code:

```
alert("Automated TradingView Extension is running");

chrome.tabs.query({
  url: 'https://www.tradingview.com/*'
}, function(tabs) {
  if (tabs.length == 1) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {subject: "testConnection"}, function(response) {
      alert(response); //THIS RETURNS UNDEFINED
      if (response.msg == "getTradingDataScriptHere") {
        alert("Script Already Injected. Do not reinject"); //THIS IS NOT RUNNING
      } else {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "jquery-2.2.3.min.js"});
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "jquery.waituntilexists.min.js"});
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "getTradingData.js"});
                alert("Injected all Nessessary Scripts for Auto Trading View to work"); //THIS IS NOT RUNNING
      }
    });
  } else {
    alert("Please have one and only one tradingview chart page opened.");
  }
});

var price = "Waiting For Price"

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.subject == "getPrice") {
      sendResponse({
        price: price
      });
    } else if (request.from == "getTradingData" && request.subject == "scriptLoaded") {
        //getTradingData.js Script has Fully Loaded onto Website

    } else if (request.from == "getTradingData" && request.subject == "updatePrice") {
        price = request.price
    }
  });
```

However the response return as undefined. So basically I am not getting a response back.

Here is what I have in my getTradingData.js that should respond to the message:

```
 alert("getTradingData.js is Running");

//Send message to let the extension know the script has been injected on site
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    from:    'getTradingData',
    subject: 'scriptLoaded'
});

chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) { //THIS DOESN'T WORK EITHER
  console.assert(port.name == "tradingdata");
  port.onMessage.addListener(function(request) {
    if (request.msg == "Knock knock")
      port.postMessage({subject: "price"});
    else if (msg.answer == "Madame")
      port.postMessage({question: "Madame who?"});
    else if (msg.answer == "Madame... Bovary")
      port.postMessage({question: "I don't get it."});
  });
});

//to check if script already injected
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    alert("got message"); //THIS IS NOT RUNNING
    if (request.subject == "testConnection") {
        sendResponse({msg: "getTradingDataScriptHere"});
    }
 });

//wait till item has loaded
$(".dl-header-figures").waitUntilExists(function(){
    alert($(".dl-header-figures").text());
    updatePrice();
});

function updatePrice(){
    alert("updating price");
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        from:    'getTradingData',
        subject: 'updatePrice',
        price: $(".dl-header-figures").text()
    });
}

//TODO: Use long lived connections for this to work: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging
// setInterval(updatePrice(), 3000);
```

However this never gets activated, I never get the alert "got message".

Here is what my manifest.json looks like:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Automated TradingView Strategy",
  "description": "This extension shows a Google Image search result for the current page",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery-2.2.3.min.js", "background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.tradingview.com/chart/*", "http://www.tradingview.com/*"],
      "js": ["jquery-2.2.3.min.js", "jquery.waituntilexists.min.js", "getTradingData.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "*://*.tradingview.com/*",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
  ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I make it send a response back. Even when I refresh extension which should reload background.js without reloading tabs which already has the content script injected in it I get no response because the Listener is not activated.

Comment: There's a typo in your manifest, `http` where potentially `https` or `*` should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to do exactly in your background script?

`chrome.tabs.query` runs only once when you load the extension, also, the scripts you are injecting with  `chrome.tabs.executeScript` should be injected already because of the manifest.

I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but, you can listen to an event every time a tab is updated (tabs are *updated* after being created) - `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener`

Updated background.js:

```
alert("Automated TradingView Extension is running");

chrome.tabs.query({
  url: 'https://www.tradingview.com/*'
}, function(tabs) {
    console.log(tabs);
  if (tabs.length == 1) {

    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {subject: "testConnection"}, function(response) {
        if (response) {
            alert("Script Already Injected. Do not reinject");
        } else {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "jquery-2.2.3.min.js"});
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "jquery.waituntilexists.min.js"});
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "getTradingData.js"});
                alert("Injected all Nessessary Scripts for Auto Trading View to work");
        }
    });
  } else {
    alert("Please have one and only one tradingview chart page opened.");
  }
});

var price = "Waiting For Price"

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.subject == "getPrice") {
      sendResponse({
        price: price
      });
    } else if (request.from == "getTradingData" && request.subject == "scriptLoaded") {
        //getTradingData.js Script has Fully Loaded onto Website

    } else if (request.from == "getTradingData" && request.subject == "updatePrice") {
        price = request.price
    }
  });
```

Comment: You're jumping to conclusion that it's the _only_ code in `background.js`. There's not enough evidence for that.

Comment: What I am trying to do is have the script that has been injected into the tradingview.com/chart/* page to communicate with the background script. But make sure that the script is always injected even if the tab is not reloaded and only extension is. I have edited to add all my code above.

Comment: @Pabi Now that I see the full source I think I know one of the problems. You're querying for a tab that has that website opened already. But if it was open already before loading the extension, it will not have any content script there listening for messages... thus the undefined. If you check for chrome.runtime.lastError I'm sure you will see some message saying that it could not establish connection.